# Left side of a floating point number in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query returning a column of floating point numbers but I am only interested in the number before the decimal place.  I don't want to round the number so I am looking for something like:

```
1.95 = 1
1.45678 = 1
12.00 = 12
12.9999 = 12
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this in SqlServer other than doing a substring?

Comment: I marked FLOOR() as the answer because it was what I was looking for but CAST() and ROUND() would work equally as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [floor function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx).

Comment: Floor does not work for negative numbers - floor(-1.2) yields -2.

Comment: Thanks. Floor is the function I was looking for. The numbers are all positive so I can live with the negative numbers issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this -

```
SELECT CAST(1.230 AS INT)
```

Output: 1

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROUND(expression, 0, 1)` to truncate a number in T-SQL. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) for reference.